# The given equation is either linear or equivalent to a linear equation. Solve the equation.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The given equation is either linear or equivalent to a linear equation. Solve the equation.

$$\frac{14x-5}{7x+3}=2-\frac{6}{x}$$

Comment: You need to add parentheses to make this more readable as it can be interpreted various ways. Also, what have tried and what are your thoughts? Regards

Comment: That doesn't look linear at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not the only way, but if you applied long division to the left hand side, you could write
$$
\begin{align*}
 \frac{14x-5}{7x+3}&=2-\frac{6}{x} \\
\Rightarrow  2 -\frac{11}{7x+3}&=2-\frac{6}{x} \\
\Rightarrow -\frac{11}{7x+3}&=-\frac{6}{x} \\
\Rightarrow \frac{11}{7x+3}&=\frac{6}{x} \\
\Rightarrow 11x&=42x+18 \\
\Rightarrow 31x&=-18 \\
\Rightarrow x&=-\frac{18}{31}.
\end{align*}
$$

Answer (score 0):

This is not a linear equation but if you take the common denominator of the right hand side and multiply the whole equation by $x(7x+3)$ you can get rid of the denominators to get a quadratic equation. Then you would be able to find values for $x$.